# Cannot read property 'props' of undefined in child component

Tags: reactjs

I get the error: "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" if I run the following  code. Both files are in the same folder. Can you please explain what am I doing wrong?

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import SeasonDisplay from './SeasonDisplay';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    lat: null,
    errorMessage: ''
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        this.setState({
          lat: position.coords.latitude
        });
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.setState({ errorMessage: err.message });
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.errorMessage && !this.state.lat) {
      return <div>Error: {this.state.errorMessage}</div>;
    }
    if (!this.state.errorMessage && this.state.lat) {
      // return <div>latitude is {this.state.lat}</div>;
      return <SeasonDisplay lat={this.state.lat} />;
    }
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

**SeasonDisplay.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const SeasonDisplay = props => {
  return <div>{props.lat}</div>;
};

export default SeasonDisplay;
```

Comment: If you don't mind using `constructor(props) { 
      super(props)                                                      
 }` in SeasonDisplay you can use `this.props.lat`

Comment: Are you getting the error in SeasonDisplay in the return line?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code and it should work...

Comment: You shouldn't have any issue with that. I recreated an example on codesandbox to show it works https://codesandbox.io/s/1o816z4zvj Are you sure you saved the file tho?

Comment: Strange! I had to start VSCode and everything is working again. Thanks for your help guys